# PhpStorm custom commenting format: surround text in an ASCII box

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'd like to accomplish the following:

1. Select this text:

   ```
   Load admin area styles and scripts
   ```
2. Press a keyboard shortcut
3. Obtain this:

   ```
   // ╔════════════════════════════════════╗
   // ║ Load admin area styles and scripts ║
   // ╚════════════════════════════════════╝
   ```

...or the same box drawn with # or * or some other characters.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your problem? Also please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) for more information

Answer (score 1):

### Record a Macro

You can record macros in PHPStorm by going into `Edit` > `Macros` > `Start Macro Recording`. This will tell PHPStorm to start "listening" to whatever you do/type. Simply type in a basic version of your code block, then stop the recording via `Edit` > `Macros` > `Stop Macro Recording`. You can then give your macro a meaningful name and invoke it whenever you want by going in `Edit` > `Macros` and selecting your macro.

### Assign the Macro to a shortcut

To assign a macro to a shortcut, you will have to open the Settings dialog (Ctrl + Alt + S) and go into the Keymap section. From there, double-click the macro you just recorded select "Add Keyboard Shortcut" and enter the shortcut you want to attribute to the macro. Make sure you don't overwrite any of the [default shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/keyboard-shortcuts-and-mouse-reference.html) when you do this.

---

### References

1. Recording a Macro: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/recording-macros.html
2. Keymap Management: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/keymap.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked out macros and they seem to be useful for certain things. Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question, that is how do I take it from selecting a text to surrounding it with asterisks (or #).

Comment: @Flix the only way to this *purely* within PHPStorm is by recording a macro. In your specific use case though, I would recommend checking out [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) as it will probably offer more freedom